# Firebase firestore: Cloud functions are not deploying properly

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the document data from the cloud firestore using cloud functions.But I am getting an error `Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.write@firestore.googleapis.com (Split)`

```
Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

I tried many options like updating my firebase tools, changing function name and deployed but still am getting the same error. 
 Here is the code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
        const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
        const firestore = new Firestore();
        const admin = require('firebase-admin');
        admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
        const db = admin.firestore();
        exports.splitting = functions.firestore
            .document('deyaPayUsers/{authid}/Split/{authid}/SentInvitations/{autoid}')
            .onWrite(event =>{
            const ID = event.params.authid;
            const splitid = event.params.autoid;
            var document = event.data.data();
            //retrieve the data from the database and stored into document
            var ph1 = document.Invite1.PhoneNumber;
            console.log(document);
            console.log(ph1);
           });
```

*My Database Path is*

```
/deyaPayUsers //collections
{authid}    //Document
/Split      //Collection
{authid}    //Document
/SentInvitations //Collection
{autoid}         //document
   Invite1     //object
     PhoneNumber: 987654321, //number
     Amount:21               //number
```

Comment: make sure the path is correct

Comment: @PeterHaddad I have Updated my question. This is my database path where I need to get the PhoneNumber value from invite1

Comment: Actually, my object is Invite1 I have used in the code same object but again I am getting the same error

Comment: After retrieving the document,  what do you want to do with it?

Comment: I need to compare with other path that which have a PhoneNumber value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49049307/getting-specific-field-from-the-object-datatype-in-firestore-using-cloud-function see these question I have to do these processs

Comment: When you get a deploy error, sometimes it's helpful to run the deploy with `--debug` on the command line to see if there's more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `authid` wildcard is used twice:

```
.document('deyaPayUsers/{authid}/Split/{authid}/SentInvitations/{autoid}')
```

Use unique names for each wildcard:

```
.document('deyaPayUsers/{authid}/Split/{authid2}/SentInvitations/{autoid}')
```

Comment: k I will try it

Comment: How do I retrieve fields from objects .can u suggest me